# How to refresh ListView after filling it asynchronously

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I set the function the returns the `ArrayList` that contains the data for ListView in `doInBackground` function in `AsyncTask`, and set the `notifyDataSetCahnged()` in onPostExecute()

but the daat is nto reflected on the listview, despite there is data in the arraylist ?
why ?

### code:

```
public class E0XMLParsing_RSSExampleActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvFeeds;
    FeedsAdapter feedsAdapter;
    ArrayList<Feed> listOfFeeds;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listOfFeeds = new ArrayList<Feed>();
        lvFeeds = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFeeds);
        feedsAdapter = new FeedsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, listOfFeeds);
        String url = "http://www.aljazeera.com/Services/Rss/?PostingId=200772215035764169";
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Aljazeera RSS", 
                                    "Please wait while downloading the RSS feeds ...");
        new DownloadRSS().execute(url);
    }


    private class DownloadRSS extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,ArrayList<Feed>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Feed> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

            return parser.getFeedsList(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Feed> listOfFeeds2){
            progress.dismiss();
            listOfFeeds = listOfFeeds2;
            feedsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

FeedAdapter

```
public class FeedsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feed>{

    public ArrayList<Feed> listOfFeeds= null;
    Context context;
    public FeedsAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Feed> feeds) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId,feeds);
        this.listOfFeeds = feeds;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view,ViewGroup parent){
        View v= view;
        if (v!=null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
            Feed f = listOfFeeds.get(position);

            TextView lblTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);
            TextView lblDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);
            TextView lblDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDate);

            lblTitle.setText(f.title);
            lblDescription.setText(f.description);
            lblDate.setText(f.date);
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: what does FeedsAdapter do? and what does it extend?, post the adapter code too.

Comment: you should change the arraylist that is inside your FeedsAdapter! so add a function that is setArray(ArrayList) inside FeedsAdapter and update the array inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `listOfFeeds = listOfFeeds2;` it sets new object reference to your object **listOfFeeds** and make it useless to call **notifyDataSetChanged** on adapter. To deal this, you may do two things in **onPostExecute**.

First:

```
listOfFeeds.clear();
listOfFeeds.addAll(listOfFeeds2);
feedsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

* *In this approach you are clearing **listOfFeeds** and pushing the items from second object causing not to change the data object reference for adapter. So you need to call notifyDataSetChanged to update the list*

Second:

```
feedsAdapter = new FeedsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
       R.layout.row, listOfFeeds);
listOfFeeds.setAdapter(feedsAdapter);
```

**In this approach, you are simply setting new adapter. So you dont need to call notifyDataSetChanged here*

Comment: You can add a whole list to a list: `listOfFeeds.addAll(listOfFeeds2)` It's also faster than doing it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that answers your question but in order to update your ListView, first you have to update the adapter, then set the adapter at the ListView and finally draw again the ListView

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewStringArray);
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myListView.invalidate() //if you perform the re-draw in UI thread
// OR myListView.postInvalidate() if you perform the re-draw in non-UI thread
```

Answer (score -1):

In `onPostExecute()`, put all your data in a `runOnUiThread()` call:

```
runonuithread () {
    feedsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't onPostExcute runs om UI by itself ?!

Comment: I dont know exactly but you are saying data is in arraylist and you are refreshing also then may be.. one more thing you can try is E0XMLParsing_RSSExampleActivity.feedsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: hey where you are setting adapter in listview

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhh, I missed it as ,, but I added it now.. and having the same issue

Comment: after adding also same issue is it crashing

Comment: **onPostExecute** always run on UI thread. So it has nothing to with using **runOnUiThread**

Comment: ya actually i have not use my mind at that time if it will not be in uithread then progressbar and notifydatasetchanged will make your activity crash. so it was already in ui thread thanks..